# How to play audio in windows mobile 6.0 apps?

Tags: windows-mobile

i'm placing audio files in one .resx file .i want to play audio in my app.
then how to get that audio path from .resx file and hoe to play that audio when click on button
.can u give some example for that one.

Comment: What type of audio file (WAV, MP3, etc)?  Using what language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For playing sounds you can use p/invoke

```
[DllImport("coredll.dll")]
    public static extern int PlaySound(
        string szSound,
        IntPtr hModule,
        int flags);


public enum PlaySoundFlags : int
{
    SND_SYNC = 0x0,     // play synchronously (default)
    SND_ASYNC = 0x1,    // play asynchronously
    SND_NODEFAULT = 0x2,    // silence (!default) if sound not found
    SND_MEMORY = 0x4,       // pszSound points to a memory file
    SND_LOOP = 0x8,     // loop the sound until next sndPlaySound
    SND_NOSTOP = 0x10,      // don't stop any currently playing sound
    SND_NOWAIT = 0x2000,    // don't wait if the driver is busy
    SND_ALIAS = 0x10000,    // name is a registry alias
    SND_ALIAS_ID = 0x110000,// alias is a predefined ID
    SND_FILENAME = 0x20000, // name is file name
    SND_RESOURCE = 0x40004, // name is resource name or atom
}
```

In order to play the sound you can use this.

```
PlaySound(@"notify.wav", IntPtr.Zero,
 (int) PlaySoundFlags.SND_FILENAME | PlaySoundFlags.SND_ASYNC);
```